# Contrast reduction - intel x86

Tags: assembly, bitmap, x86, intel

I was supposed to do a project to pass my course. I would like to ask, if there is any possibility to make my code more effective or just better. I'm doing it because my coordinator is a very meticulous perfectionist and crazy about efficiency. 
It's a hybrid program, it modifies a 24bpp bitmap. It's a contrast reduction, algorithm looks like this(it's approved by my coordinator):

```
comp-=128;
comp*=rfactor
comp/=128
comp+=128
```

'comp' means every component of a pixel, literally: every value of red, green and blue in every pixel. 
The function does just this, I read from file using another functions in C. I forward to assembly an array with components, the width of the bmp, amount of pixels in each line, and the 'rfactor' - value of contrast reduction. then I just make this:

```
;  void contrast(void *img, int width, int lineWidth, int rfactor);
;   stack:  EBP+8 ->        *img
;       EBP+12 ->       width [px]
;       EBP+16 ->       lineWidth [B]
;       EBP+20 ->       rfactor (values in range of 1-128)
section .text 
global  contrast

contrast:
push    ebp         
mov ebp, esp     

push    ebx         
mov     ebx, [ebp+12]   ; width
mov     eax, [ebp+16]   ; lineWidth
mul     ebx     ; how much pixels to reduce
mov     ecx, eax    ; set counter
mov     edx, [ebp+8]    ; edx = pointer at img
mov     ebx, [ebp+20]   ; ebx=rfactor

loop:
xor     eax, eax    
dec     ecx         ; decrement counter
mov     al, [edx]   ; current pixel to al
add     eax, -128   
imul    bl          ; pixel*rfactor
sar     eax, 7      ; pixel/128
add     eax, 128    
mov     byte[edx], al   ; put the pixel back
inc     edx         ; next pixel
test    ecx, ecx    ; is counter 0?
jnz     loop        

koniec:
pop     ebx
mov     esp, ebp    
pop     ebp
ret
```

Is there anything to improve? Thank you for all suggestions, I have to impress my coordinator ;)

Comment: are you allowed to use extensions like SSE 4.x and/or AVX?

Comment: @knm241 yes I am, but I have no idea how to use it in this case

Comment: I'm not sure it's worth using SSE4.x/AVX as they require a recent CPU to be tested. I have written a sketch of a code using SIMD instrunctions, need to do some tests. Anyway some micro optimization you could do: 1) Use `loop` instruction instead of `jnz loop` so you can avoid a `dec ecx`. 2) don't zero eax 3)rewrite your equation from `out = (in-128)*r/128 + 128` to `out = (in*r >> 7) + 128 - r` so you can precompute `128 -r` before the cycle and simplify the loop (now it should be possible to use `shr` as `in*r` is positive. 4)unroll the loop to process 4 pixel at a time loading them together

Comment: I maybe wrong with the optimizations suggested above, please take it with a grain of salt :) I'll look for a SIMD version for completeness.

Comment: @knm241 I would be very, very grateful for those SIMD version.
I'll try those optimizations, thank you for them!

Comment: Minor: put `128` into an unused register (perhaps `esi` – *but* see further!) and use this in `add eax, -128` and `add eax, 128`. Instead of `edx`, use `esi` to index your image; then you can use `stosb` instead of `mov [edx],al / inc edx`. Most of all: *profile all of your changes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you are still interested in a SIMD version here is one.
It use AVX2 instructions so you need at least a 4th generation processor (Haswell micro-architecture).

```
BITS 32

GLOBAL _contrast

SECTION .code

;rfactor
;lineWidth 
;width
;ptr to buffer
_contrast:
    push ebp         
    mov ebp, esp     

    and esp, 0fffffff0h

    push edi
    push esi
    push ebx 
    push eax


    mov eax, DWORD [ebp+0ch]        ;witdh
    mul DWORD [ebp+10h]             ;total bytes
    mov ecx, eax                    ;Number of bytes to process
    shr ecx, 04h                    ;Process chunks of 16 bytes per cycle

    mov edi, DWORD [ebp+08h]        ;Buffer


    ;--- Prepare ymm registers ---

    vzeroall

    sub esp, 10h 

    ;ymm1 contains the r factor (x16)
    movzx ebx, WORD [ebp+14h]
    mov DWORD [esp], ebx
    vpbroadcastw ymm1, WORD [esp]   ;ymm1 = r (x16)

    ;ymm0 contains the 128-r value (x16)
    neg WORD [esp]                  ;-r
    mov al, 128
    add WORD [esp], ax              ;128-r
    vpbroadcastw ymm0, WORD [esp]   ;ymm0 = 128-r (x16)

    add esp, 10h

.loop:
    ;Computer channels values
    vpmovzxbw ymm2, [edi]           ;16 channels (128 bit) to 16 words
    vpmullw ymm2, ymm2, ymm1        ;ymm2 = in*r
    vpsrlw ymm2, ymm2, 7            ;ymm2 = in*r>>7
    vpaddw ymm2, ymm2, ymm0         ;ymm2 = in*r>>7 + r-128

    vpackuswb ymm2, ymm2, ymm2      ;xmm2 = 16 computes values 

    ;Store to memory
    movdqa [edi], xmm2

    add edi, 10h

loop .loop

    pop eax
    pop ebx
    pop esi
    pop edi 

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

I have tested it by comparing its output with the output of your code.

The prototype in C is your old one (with lineWidth):

```c
void contrast(void* buffer, unsigned int width, unsigned int Bpp, unsigned short rfactor);
```

I have done some profiling on my machine. I have run this version and the one in your answer on a 2048x20480 image (120MiB buffer) 10 times. Your code takes 2.93 seconds, this one 1.09 seconds. Though this timings may not be very accurate.

This version require a buffer size that is a multiple of 16 (because it processes 16 bytes per cycle, 5 and one third of pixel at a time), you can pad with zeros. If the buffer is aligned on 16 byte boundaries it will run faster.

If you want a more detailed answer (with useful comments for example :D) just ask in the comments.

**EDIT**: Updated the code with the **great** help of Peter Cordes, for future reference.

Comment: Why are you using `vinserti128` twice?  The first one can be `vmovdqu`, which doesn't need any port 015 uops (and breaks any dependency on the old value of the `ymm` reg.)  Also, you could just use `vpbroadcastd` to broadcast a 32bit value to all elements of a `ymm`, rather than 4x `push`.  For the store, `vextracti128 [esp], ymm0, 0` is 100% equivalent to `vmovdqu [esp], xmm0`.  I think it only exists (instead of a storehigh128) so it will work the same in avx-512, where the imm8 will index one of 4 possible 128 lanes.

Comment: also, instead of a `lodsd`/`stosb` sequence, couldn't you shift every other byte with something like `vpsrlw` and then a `vpblendsomething` to end up with a register holding the desired combo of shifted bytes and non-shifted bytes?  And use `vpackuswb` to go back to 8bit lanes, from 16bit.

Comment: sure. there a whole lotta AVX2 instructions all mixed up with non AVX instructions in the Intel manual and I missed the `vpbroadcastsd`. For the `loadsd`/`stosd` there are surely better methods, but that turned out to be fast. Feel free to use the code for your answer if needed!

Comment: @PeterCordes following your suggestion I updated the code. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention this before, but `packuswb` does the inverse operation to `punpckbw`.  Unpack your input with an all-zero reg (instead of `pmovzxbw`), and then you can put everything back in-order with a single `packuswb`.  I haven't taken the time to fully grok what's going on in this algo, so I won't post an answer of my own.  Thanks for taking my suggestions; your answer looks a lot better without those string ops to a temp buffer :P

Comment: @PeterCordes good point!  Updated the code, removed ugly `ymm3` and `ymm4` initialization. I have no `punpckbw` instruction in my manual, anyway `pmovzxbw` works great for this job. You deserve this answer points more than me now! :P

Comment: Silly me: `punpcklbw` and `punpckhbw` to get 256b of src data unpacked into two ymm registers.  Which you can then recombine with `packuswb`.  The trick is that `pmovzxbw` moves data between 128b lanes, while `punpck` and `pack` don't, so `packuswb` is *not* an inverse to `pmovzx`.  (Unpacking to a high half and low half means you need to replicate the computation for both halves.  Having two dependency chains going at once is good for throughput, if latency was a limiting factor.  It isn't here, since the loop is much shorter than the re-order buffer, and each iteration is independent.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82216/discussion-between-knm241-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: BTW, for finding useful insns, Agner Fog's optimizing assembly guide has a nice set of tables of various data-movement operations, with instructions that can impelement them.  One is for ways to broadcast an element.  (e.g. `pshufd` or `pshufb` to broadcast an arbitrary element within a 128b lane.)  http://agner.org/optimize/

Answer (score 0):

You may squeeze a little more out of your loop when not up-counting, but downcounting, like this (I changed the header to indicate the meaning, and I omitted the trailer:

```
    mov edx, img
    mov ecx, width*lineWidth  ; pseudo-assembler here
    mov ebx, rfactor
loop:
        xor  eax, eax
        mov  al, [ecx+edx-1]
        sub  eax, 128
        imul bl
        sar  eax, 7
        add  eax, 128
        mov  byte ptr[ecx+edx-1], al
        dec  ecx
        jnz  loop
; add trailer here
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed. Thank for all your suggestions. I hope my coordinator will be satisfied. If not, I would be forced to do it using vectors
    ;  void contrast(void *img, int pixels, int rfactor);
    ;   stack:  EBP+8 ->        *img
    ;           EBP+12 ->       counter (how much bytes to modify)
    ;           EBP+16 ->       rfactor
    section .text 
    global  contrast

```
contrast:
push    ebp 
mov     ebp, esp     
push    ebx 
push    edi

mov     ecx, [ebp+12]   ; set counter
mov ebx, [ebp+16]   ; rfactor to ebx
mov edi, [ebp+8]    ; img pointer
mov dl, 128     
sub dl, bl      ; 128-rfactor

loop:
mov al, [edi]  ; current pixel to al
mul bl      ;
shr ax, 7   ; byte*rfactor>>7+(128-rfactor)
add al, dl  ;
stosb           ; store al, inc edi
loop loop   

koniec: 
pop     edi
pop     ebx
mov     esp, ebp    
pop     ebp
ret
```

Comment: On pre-Nehalem Intel CPUs, that 16bit `shr` is going to be slow to decode every time through the loop.  (later CPUs have a loop buffer big enough to hold all the uops for that small loop.)

Comment: There's not much point to writing directly in asm if you're not going to use the vector instructions, esp. for something like graphics, IMO.  Is your asm version much faster than a C compiler?